# How do I run a .exe in the system tray?

Tags: windows-xp

I have an exe that is continuously running. Instead of having an open window all the time, Can it be minimized to the system tray?

Comment: What language/framework are you using? In .NET you can create a Windows Service project.

Comment: many programs nowadays have a "Minimize to Tray" option somewhere. otherwise, you may have to use a service daemon.

Comment: is it a program you developed, if yes in which language ? or just use (in this case should be asked in superuser rather than stack overflow)

Comment: It was developed in vc++

Answer (score 0):

[Shell_NotifyIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona) is a good entry point for you.